# Concat javascript dynamic variable with HTML helper's Id In ASP.NET MVC razor view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC project In the razor view I written a script and a part of that is as below :

```
<script>
         var a =
                '<table>' +
                '<tbody><tr>' +
                '<td><input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="'+parentId+'_CheckBox" ></td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<td><div class="AttachementTypeLookup">@Html.TextBox("Attachement_LookUp", text, htmlAttributes)</div></td>' +
                '</tbody></table>';
</script>
```

as you see there is an html helper in this script as below :

```
@Html.TextBox("Attachement_LookUp", text, htmlAttributes)
```

I have a javascript dynamic variable and I must concat this dynamic variable with "Attachement_LookUp" in this HTML helper.
How can I do this. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the relationship between server-side code (Razor) and client-side code (javascript).   Think of it as a (snail-mail) letter - Razor writes the letter then sends it via the post office to the client where the client can then make changes.  From this you should be able to clearly see that javascript can't change razor as the razor has finished before it gets to javascript.

Comment: Having said that, `var a = '<div>@Html.TextBox(...)' + your_variable + '</div>'` - not really sure what you want your end result to be.  "Concat a variable with an `<input>'` doesn't really make much sense - can you give an example of what the end html would look like?